# Change format of variables in SAS using case-when or proc import

Tags: sql, database, sas

I have multiple tables that were imported from txt files using PROC IMPORT. I want to rbind join together but some of the column formats don't match.

Table 1:

| ID (num) | CODE (num) | Descr (char) | zip (num) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 8 | Desc 1 | 91023 |
| 02 | 10 | Descr 2 | 60603 |

Table 2:

| ID (char) | CODE (num) | Descr (char) | zip (char) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 10 | Desc 2 | Unknown |
| A2 | 15 | Descr 3 | Unknown |

Table 3:

| ID (num) | CODE (num) | Descr (char) | zip (char) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 80 | 20 | Desc 2 | Unknown |
| 83 | 16 | Descr 3 | Unknown |

Final output:

| ID (char) | CODE (num) | Descr (char) | zip (char) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 8 | Desc 1 | 91023 |
| 02 | 10 | Descr 2 | 60603 |
| A1 | 10 | Desc 2 | Unknown |
| A2 | 15 | Descr 3 | Unknown |
| 80 | 20 | Desc 2 | Unknown |
| 83 | 16 | Descr 3 | Unknown |

There's more than 3 tables and there are multiple columns that don't match in formats. I have an idea for what formats I want for each column (In this example I want the format to look like Table 3's).

My goal is to make a macro function where for each table I can see what the variable type is, and then depending on if I need the column to be character or numeric, use a case when statement to change the column to be the correct format.
I first tried to get the vtype and then use a case-when statement.

```
   data table1_type;
    set table1;
       id_var = vtype(ID); /*want the final col to be char*/
       code_var = vtype(code);  /*want the final col to be num*/
       descr_var = vtype(descr);  /*want the final col to be char*/
       zip_var = vtype(zip);  /*want the final col to be char*/
    run;

 proc sql;
    create table table1_format as 
    select * ,
       case when id_var = "N" then put(id, 4.) else ID end as ID_reformat 
/*If the ID is numeric then I want it converted into a character, but if it's a character then I want it to output still as a character*/
    from table1_type;
    quit;
```

But I get this error: Result of WHEN clause 2 is not the same data type as the preceding results.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to try and tackle this problem. Would anyone have a better way? Thank you.

Edit:
my PROC IMPORT statement looks like this:

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= WORK.table1
DATAFILE= "filelocation/table1.txt"
DBMS=DLM REPLACE;
DELIMITER='|';
guessingrows = max;
RUN;
```

Comment: What is the actual problem?  You appear to be stuck on trying the fix the issue caused by the choice of method.  It would help to know the actual issue and its root cause.   A common source of inconsistent variable types is having to use a guessing procedure to read in the data.  But if the source files are TEXT files you can just write the code that reads them so that they variable types are the same in each file.

Comment: Okay, now my question is, how do you edit the Proc import statement in order to have the correct formats? I'll edit my question more to these specifications.

Comment: Do not use PROC IMPORT to read important files.  It is great to do a quick a dirty look at the data.  But for real data write your own data step to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to read the files consistently in the first place.

Let's create two text files that look like your first two examples to have something we can code with.

```
options parmcards=file1;
filename file1 temp;
parmcards;
ID (num),CODE (num),Descr (char),zip (num)
01,8,Desc 1,91023
02,10,Descr 2,60603
;

options parmcards=file2;
filename file2 temp;
parmcards;
ID (char),CODE (num),Descr (char),zip (char)
A1,10,Desc 2,Unknown
A2,15,Descr 3,Unknown
;
```

Now let's read them in using the exact same code so that we get datasets with the same variables defined in the exact same way.

```
data file1;
  infile file1 dsd truncover firstobs=2 ;
  input ID :$10. CODE DESCR :$30. ZIP :$9. ;
run;

data file2;
  infile file2 dsd truncover firstobs=2 ;
  input ID :$10. CODE DESCR :$30. ZIP :$9. ;
run;
```

Now we can easily combine the datasets together.

```
data want;
  set file1 file2;
run;
```

Results

```
OBS    ID    CODE     DESCR       ZIP

 1     01      8     Desc 1     91023
 2     02     10     Descr 2    60603
 3     A1     10     Desc 2     Unknown
 4     A2     15     Descr 3    Unknown
```

PROC IMPORT is a useful tool for doing a quick and dirty look at a file whose contents you are not familiar with. But to get control over how the variables are created just write your own code to read the text files.  As the example data steps above show that can sometimes take even less code than needed to call PROC IMPORT.